# MS Sql server to MongoDB export - on a single machine

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, sqoop

We have our software installed in our customer machines and our previous version uses MS-SQL server for years together. We have bulk data on MS-SQL server database. Now we are upgrading our application to a different technology stack which includes MongoDB as a database.

But, We do not have any distributed environment as everything runs on a single windows machine.

We need to now import all historical bulk data from MS-SQL server to MongoDB. Can someone help me what can be used to do it faster, safer and with very minimal resource usage on a single windows machine?

Comment: It is not as simple as it seems. First of all, are you simply storing data or doing any SQL query over it? MongoDB is document based NoSQL datastore. The structure of data is very different in RDBMS and NoSQL world. Check Mongo [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/rdbms-mongodb-migration-guide) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response dev.  Yes I understand the issue but what I was thinking is this is definitely not a unique problem as many of the systems are moved from SQL to NoSQL, especially mongoDB. Hence I thought there could be a framework or library which can run on windows to do this job. It is just a simple import we are not doing any pre-processing.

Comment: You can have a look at [Mongify](http://mongify.com/getting_started.html)